# SharePoint Designer and BDC issue for Production

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I created a BDC to connect external Database in the SharePoint Designer. Everything is OK and working well in SIT.

But once we go for UAT, I import this one in UAT server but don't know how to change the user name and password of the SQL server in the BDC model.

So I request my client to install the SharePoint Designer in UAT server and do everything from the start.

I am told that they will not allow me to install SharePoint Designer in production server.

How can I change the user name of password of the SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to how you change the credentials but in SPD you just specify the URL of the site you wish to connect to.

You could make the changes from from SPD in your development enviroment just spedcify the URL to the live site.

Hope this helps.